# Mapbox Android : Adjust Opacity of background layer

Tags: kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm searching the way to adjust the opacity of the mapbox map. In the following example, `layers[0]` refers to the background layer.

```
mapboxMap.style!!.layers[0]?.setProperties(rasterOpacity(0.3f))
```

Applying this code has no effect. What is wrong ?

Comment: Android SDK >= 2.0.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
style.getLayer("layer_name").setProperties(
   rasterOpacity(0.3)
)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.